# On-device single-word voice recognition

Tags: voice-recognition

Does needing just a single word voice recognition reduce the complexity of the task enough to be able to fully perform voice recognition processing *offline*, on an iOS or Android smartphone? (E.g., could a reasonably accurate counter for the number of times that a single, pre-programmed word was spoken while the microphone is active be developed to work offline on a standard iOS or Android smartphone?).

I've found plenty of tools and examples capturing voice and sending it to an online service (e.g., the Google cloud voice-to-text), but does the single-word focus reduce the complexity enough for the recognition to be doable *offline* today? If so, do you have any libraries to suggest or where would you start?

Comment: You can check snowboy.

Comment: Oh, looks promising -- I'll give it a shot and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Cloud services are good for various reasons relating to your question:

1. It makes deployment of new versions of the algorithm (which happen *much* more frequently than most people realize) a lot easier
2. It allows the developer to collect your data and use it in future algorithm development (or whatever they please)
3. From a practical standpoint, most deployed models (at least the effective ones) can be quite large and take up quite a bit of space on a mobile device.

In addition to the above, I don't think that the singular word focus changes much, if anything. The model has to not just account for words, but also for the different ways those words can be said (volume, tone, accents, inflection, etc, etc).

So what you are asking *can* be done but there's also good reasons why it's on the cloud.

Comment: Sure, I agree on all those points. However, the question was specifically about on-device possibilities since there won't necessarily be an internet connection.

Comment: @medeny I think my answer makes it clear that you can do this but there's a lot of reasons why you shouldn't. You would be creating a device to do just one thing and it wouldn't do it very well  once the algorithm aged with no updates.